# Performance of alloca

Tags: c++, performance, stack, alloca

I'm using `alloca` a lot these days, to allocate temporary buffers. In my application (signal processing) this is a common need.

The question is:

When allocating multiple arrays, is it better (performance-wise) to use alloca just once?

Like this:

```
float *array1 = (float*)alloca(4096 * 4);
float *array2 = array1 + 1024;
float *array3 = array2 + 1024;
float *array4 = array3 + 1024;
```

Or use it multiple times like this:

```
void *array1 = (float*)alloca(4096);
void *array2 = (float*)alloca(4096);
void *array3 = (float*)alloca(4096);
void *array4 = (float*)alloca(4096);
```

I mean all it probably does is decrease the stack pointer and probably do the "stack probe", which depends on the size, so it perhaps doesn't matter?

Comment: Like all performance questions, measure and find out.

Comment: It likely doesn't matter. As with most performance issues, the only way to be sure is to try it both ways and measure.

Comment: `alloca` is super dangerous. Prefer to only use it for very small amounts of data.

Comment: Also check and compare what code the compiler generates for both cases.

Comment: Oh, and remember to do all benchmarking, measuring or assembly comparison after you build with optimizations enabled.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource maybe have a look at this

Comment: Is the `alloca`ted size constant for the benefit of a simple example or is it actually constant? If it is, why use `alloca` at all? An automatic buffer (c-array, `std::array`, take your pick) would suffice there.

Comment: Why is `alloca` a common need in Signal Processing?  I would expect that Signal Processing would use pre-allocated (or global) arrays because dynamic allocation can lead to fragmentation.  Many Signal Processing programs are written for efficiency and dynamic allocation of memory is not efficient (searching for available blocks of memory is less efficient than using predeclared arrays).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's not a common need, the arrays are common need and you just don't know how big they will be up to a certain constraint. Allocation on stack is just the fastest way. Of course, it is dangerous, but when you are pretty much certain it won't exceed a certain threshold, it is fine. I'm using it for years and tried several other approaches before.

Answer (score 3):

`alloca` is made to be faster than `malloc` for reasons related with the way the allocation/deallocation is performed, and the sections of memory used, as I'm sure you know. It's also, as stated in the comments, very easy to get wrong.

To the point, my guess would be that the first version, repeating `alloca`, would be faster, in an unoptimized setting, than playing with indirection, and indeed, after some benchmarks this was confirmed:

[image]

The tests were performed using [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark), clang 10.0, C++20 std and no optimization. The tests were repeated with constant results using function runs with code similar to that of the OP:

```
#include <alloca.h>

void alloc1(){
    float *array1 = (float*)alloca(4096 * 4);
    float *array2 = array1 + 1024;
    float *array3 = array2 + 1024;
    float *array4 = array3 + 1024;
}

void alloc2(){
    void *array1 = (float*)alloca(4096);
    void *array2 = (float*)alloca(4096);
    void *array3 = (float*)alloca(4096);
    void *array4 = (float*)alloca(4096);
}

static void alloca1_test(benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        alloc1();
        //benchmark::DoNotOptimize();
    }
}
BENCHMARK(alloca1_test);

static void alloca2_test(benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        alloc2();
        //benchmark::DoNotOptimize();
    }
}
BENCHMARK(alloca2_test);
```

Whith `O3` otpimization added, as one would expect, the test results will even out, the multiple `alloca` still consistently slightly faster but the differences in performance are negligible. As you stated, it's basicaly the same. To use one or the other seems to make little to no difference.

[image]

Disclaimer:

To best understand the performance of your program, integrated testing would give you a more accurate reading than isolated testing like done here. The buils tools as well as the environment will also affect the end result, to fully and accurately measure the performance of your options you must test them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The usefulness of `alloca` is if you don't know the size of your array upfront.

For the given code, it is not different from simply writing:

```
float array1[4096];
float array2[4096];
float array3[4096];
float array4[4096];
```

Frankly, I don't see the need for benchmarking; `alloca` just bumps a stack pointer to make space for your allocation, just like declaration of those arrays does.

Comment: Of course, but I don't know the size before, the example was just to demonstrate the situation.